# Unable to translate line 76, on CouponManagement.php

Tags: magento2

Unable to translate line 76 on Magento 2.3.3 
/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/CouponManagement.php
"The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again."

Copy Paste of my actual translation dictionary
"The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again.","El cupon no es valido. Verifica e intentalo de nuevo.",module,Magento_Quote

Tested everthing, flushing cache..removing every cache files, all the basics. If i directly modify the file it works, but is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Coupon request on checkout is coming from web api, so theme translation is not in the scope of API.

A workaround is to set that translation into a custom module like this:
app/code/Custom/Module/i18n/es_ES.csv

"The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again.","El cupon no es valido. Verifica e intentalo de nuevo.",module,Magento_Quote

Answer (score 0):

This a bug because M2 loaded csv of pack before theme. You can change translation in /vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-vietnamese-language-pack/vi_VN.csv and you will see it

Answer (score 0):

You have more than option.
add your translation in the design folder "module dependent"

> app\design\frontend\VendorName\ThemeName\Magento_Quote\i18n\es_ES.csv

`"The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again.","El cupon no es valido. Verifica e intentalo de nuevo."`

or as a language package in

> app\i18n\es_ES.csv

like `"The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again.","El cupon no es valido. Verifica e intentalo de nuevo.",module,Magento_Quote`

Then you have to flush cash and redeploy your static files

`bin/magento cache:flush`

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`